# How to read XML using Linq with Nested Descendants

Tags: c#, linq

How to read the elements inside nested descendants in LINQ

My Xml file format

```
<SmPpProperties>
 <PpProperties>
   <Project Name="CEESI all 2" CreatedDate="2013-11-18T16:48:54.9452592+01:00" ModifiedDate="2013-11-18T16:48:57.2413905+01:00">
      <NuclearSystem>Barium</NuclearSystem>
      <TimeLine>
          <Clip>
            <FilePathFP>FPS\FP001D\Default-wp000-15Oct2012-105001.vxbin</FilePathFP>
          </Clip>
      </TimeLine>
   </Project>
  </PpProperties>
</SmPpProperties>
```

I am trying to use C # code as

```
var SmPpProperties
      = from PpProperties in xmldoc.Descendants("PpProperties")
        select new
        {
            from Project in xmldoc.Descendants("Project ")
            select new { 
           *How to proceed*
```

Comment: What data do you need from your XML?

Comment: @ Marcin I am looking for n No.of <FilePathFP> values </FilePathFP> present inside n no of <Clip> </Clip> and try to add them in a list using Linq

Comment: You don't want to use `from Project in xmldoc.Descendants("Project ")` anyway, for two reasons. Firstly, you've got a space at the end of the element name, and secondly surely you only want the `Project` elements *within the current `PpProperties` element*. So you should be using `PpProperties.Elements("Project")`.

Comment: Also, it's hard to know exactly what structure you're looking for in the returned data - and what structure is in the XML. You've only given a single example of each element - which elements can have multiple occurrences, and how do you want to handle them?

Comment: @ Jon Skeet  I am looking for these following values - I am beginner in lang integrated query and C#                                <Clip> <FilePathFp> ****</FilePathFp>                                              <From> **** </From>                                                           <To> **** </To>                                                      </Clip> and so on till </Timeline>

Answer (score 0):

```
var SmPpProperties = from poj in xmldoc.Descendants("Project")
                     select new {name = poj.Attribute("Name"), 
                                 filePath = poj.Element("TimeLine").Element("Clip").Element("FilePathFP").Value};

 foreach (var item in SmPpProperties)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Name = {0}, File Path = {1}", item.name, item.filePath);
 }
```

Comment: @ Lomed Thanks for your Reply. I would like to print those attributes in console application and also the values after selecting them using select statement. How shud i use

Comment: @ Lomed Thanks a lot! It helped much.....I am also learning to add those items in a list like this                                           Clips = Clip.Element("Clips")
                  .Elements()
                  .Select(c => (string)c)
                  .ToList()                                             am i doing it right ?

Comment: @ Lomed : One more help , I have plenty of Clip tags inside the single Timeline. Hoe to extract all the FilePath present in many clips tags say 10 sets of clip tags.

Comment: @ Lomed : Your solution is very much accepted. Thanks